# How to increase fit of high values (generalised linear mixed model)?

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

My dataset consists of ~800 observations. This is the distribution of my response variable:

[image]

I'd like to model the response with a generalised linear mixed model with 1 random effect and 8 fixed effects. I've tried different families and links but in any case when I compare observed vs. fitted values I can see that the few very high values of the response variable are modelled poorly.

Model fit with gaussian family and log link (best of all I tried):
[image]

What can I try to increase the fit?

Comment: Have you also tried non-linear associations (transforming variables [predictor or outcome] to for example, log scale; or fractional polynomials; or [restricted] cubic splines)?

Comment: On the residual plot, which axis are the predictions?

Comment: @IWS I tried transforming the response variable to no avail

Comment: I would recommend you to look at the non-linear association types I mentioned in my previous comment. This concerns the predictor variables (independent variables) instead of the response (==outcome==dependent variable).

Answer (score 1):

Under your assumptions, it seems the data has a couple of data points that have a higher outcome than the model expects. You hope that after a logarithmic transformation the errors look Gaussian, but they do not.

You can think about what's causing the outliers. Perhaps there is something that's causing these? A nonlinear effect in one of the predictors? Or a missing predictor?

If you are confident the linear model is correct, you can try to wrestle the errors into a Gaussian. You mention you have used the log transform, that's a common one, but you can also try a couple of other transformations from the Box-Cox family, I've googled this link: https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/making-data-normal-using-box-cox-power-transformation/.